# How to set remote_user only for role?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook where I have some roles.
I have two roles for example one common where I deploy some users and set the ssh settings and another where I do some installation tasks.

I want to run the common as root and the other roles with become.

I tried to do it like:

```
  roles:
    - role: common
      vars:
        remote_user: root
```

How can I run some role as root and the others as normal user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that is currently possible. You can add a smaller play with your role as described [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5084#issuecomment-29415323)

```
- hosts: soliton-db2
  remote_user: root
  roles:
      - foo
- hosts: soliton-db2
  remote_user: alice
  roles:
      - bar
```

This SO question might be of help since you are trying to run the role with root user - [Define `become=yes' per role with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183100/define-become-yes-per-role-with-ansible)